# How to apply for jobs while in an internship

Tags: job-search, internship

I am soon to start an internship which will last 3 months and don't know how to apply for a job which I am also interested in.
Additionally, I want to email this person who works at the place (Let's call it ABC) and tell them that I'm interested in finding a job at ABC, please promote my resume if you wish, thank you goodbye etc. For simplicity let's call my internship INT (these are social sciences jobs)

So
I asked about this and was confused by the response and maybe I was a bit misunderstood. I said I made contact with some people who worked at ABC, where I am interested to find a job in. I wanted to communicate with those people  at ABC before too long, before my internship kicks in because they'd forget about who I am. I was going to email these people at ABC and tell them I am interested to find a job with their organization.

Maybe I was misunderstood because I was told that it would be awkward if I get through the job process at ABC within 3 months, they then ask me when I can start and then I tell them I'm in the middle of an internship, because usually they say we'd like you to start work tomorrow. Or worse, dropping the internship midway to start the job is a bad idea. (I think I may have been misunderstood while asking this question.)

Let me try to rephrase the question given that maybe someone was confused by me I guess?
I want to begin this job when the internship completes, but i don't know how to carry those two goals properly at the same time. I know that job searching during internships is normal, but how do I do that? Do I need to tell people I'm in an internship during the interview, or do I tell them that I'm available in 3 months AFTER the interview goes through, AFTER they said we'd like to have you work here?

And so how do I tell these people I mentioned above, who work here at ABC, I am interested in their organization but I am in an internship right now and would like to apply for a job that I could start at earliest in 3 months?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're not going to drop your internship even if they offer you a job, you need to tell the recruiter of ABC before any interview takes place. Do the same with your referral at ABC, write an email and have someone else proofread it. Your email needs to be crystal clear about the date of your availability.

Answer (score 3):

People apply for jobs with future start dates all the time:

- need to finish a project
- need to complete final exams
- completing internship
- moving accomodation

So apply, all you have to do is state the start date.